# Why is my startup script not running

Tags: linux, sh, init.d, angstrom-linux

Per various tutorials I've done the following:

created a file called `ftpserver.py` in `/home/root/`

created a file in `/etc/init.d/` called `ftpserver` that looks like this"

```
#!/bin/sh
python /home/root/ftpserver.py
```

Upon creation, I ran the following (to make it executable, apparently)

```
root@beaglebone1:/etc/init.d# chmod +x ftpserver
```

But it doesn't appear to be running on startup. However if I run the following command:

```
root@beaglebone1:/etc/init.d# /etc/init.d/ftpserver
```

Then the script runs, exectuing ftpserver.py.

Interestingly, if I try to run `ftpserver` from within it's directory in the following manner (not sure if this is relevant):

```
root@beaglebone1:/etc/init.d# ftpserver
```

It returns:

```
-sh: ftpserver: command not found
```

So I'm not certain why my script isn't running on startup.

For reference, ftpserver.py looks like this:

```
from pyftpdlib import ftpserver
authorizer = ftpserver.DummyAuthorizer()
authorizer.add_user("root", "12345", "/home/root", perm="elradfmw")
handler = ftpserver.FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer
address = ("", 21)
ftpd = ftpserver.FTPServer(address, handler)
ftpd.serve_forever(
```

Comment: Try supplying full path to `python` in `ftpserver`.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem with a script int init.d not running. I don't have a rc.conf file!

Answer (score 1):

Try running it with `./ftpserver`

Also, check if your script is configured to run in current runlevel - probably /etc/rc.conf and there `DAEMONS` or something like that.